# Google Tag Manager loads container version that is older than the default container included in the resources

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

I'm using the Google Tag Manager for Android SDK and have run into a problem.

Both the `loadContainerPreferNonDefault` and `loadContainerPreferFresh` methods download and load the published version of my container even if it is a lower version than the default container binary file I have stored in my application.

I realize there is the `loadContainerDefaultOnly` method available which is semi-useful for testing but doesn't achieve what I need.

My end goal is to be able to add variables to my container that new versions of my application will rely on. However since I am also using the container for update checking I cannot publish the new container immediately as my user's would be prompted to update to a version that hasn't been pushed to the Play Store yet.

So long story short, is there any way to override this behavior and only load a container from the network/disk is it's version is greater than that on the default container? Or is my only option to use more than one container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately all signs point to this being by design. Google Tag Manager really only cares about the published version of a container.